# Testing form submission with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a simple Cuke feature for a form on a demo site. The feature looks like this.

```
    Given I am on the home page
    When I set the "Start Date" to "2010-10-25"
    And I set the "End Date" to "2011-1-3"
    And I press the "Go" button
    Then I should see "Cake Shop"
```

The idea is that after I press the Go button, a new page will load, showing a list of results, and one of the results should be "Cake Shop."

But I have not managed to get this to work. Is there something that I am missing?

Edit: here is the step definitions.

```
Given /^I am on the "([^"]*)" page$/ do |page|
  visit root_path
end

When /^I set the "([^"]*)" to "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, date|
  fill_in field, :with=>date
end

When /^I press the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |arg1|
  click_button('Go')
end
```

The final step is defined in web_steps.rb I believe....and it's always there that it's failing.

> ```
> expected #has_content?("Cake Shop") to return true, got false
> ```
>
> (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
>       ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:110:in
>   `block (2 levels) in '

Comment: some code is in order. Specifically, your cucumber steps. Also some output as to what was failing.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat Just added the steps I am using.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're using Capybara to drive tests the step "Then show me the page" will put the HTML of the current page in to the tmp folder, take a look at that.
2. Where is the data "Cake shop" coming from? Is your database being reset before you run the tests? Usually if your cucumbers require some setup data it's best to explicitly state that the data exists with a step and insert it for each test. e.g.

   Given the item "Cake shop" exists

Comment: Yes, I am using Capybara. "Cake Shop" exists -- I ran rake db:test:prepare --and it should appear on the next page that gets loaded after the form submission. So that's the page I am trying to check, actually, not the current page. I don't know what I should use to check for that...

Comment: Current page means the page that the user would see if they'd submitted the form. So, assuming the form submitted correctly the 'current page' would be the results page or the 'next page'. Just insert the step "Then show me the page" before the "Then I should see" step. As I said before, it's much clearer to set up data manually in your steps rather than rely on you app being in an undocumented expected state before each test.